# PHP joined MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a comments system in which i will want to pull information from both tables, the problem is the results from the first query (the ID which is found) effects the output of the second query. My tables look like this.

members

Id, First_name, Last_name, Email, Password, Img_url, Activation_No, Activated, and Date

posts

PostId, Email, Text, ForumId, DatePosted, Likes, Dislikes

The code i am using is;

```
<?php
    // retrive post
    include('php/config.php');
    include ('php/function.php');

    // retrive comments with post id

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT (posts.Email,posts.Text) FROM posts WHERE posts.ForumId = '$forumId' LEFT JOIN  SELECT (members.Img_url) FROM members WHERE members.Email = (posts.Email)");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($PostId,$Email,$Text,$ForumId,$DatePosted,$Likes,$Dislikes,$usr_img);
$stmt->fetch();
    print "<div class=comment-item>";
    print   "<div class=comment-avatar>";
    print   "<img src=".$usr_img."alt=avatar>";
    print   "</div>";
    print   "<div class=comment-post>";
    print       "<h4>" .$Email. "<span> said....</span></h4>";
    print       "<p>" .$Text. "</p>";
    print   "</div>";
    print"</div>";
$stmt->close();
?>
```

The Error message i am receiving is;

> Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\Users\PC\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\post.php on line 90

Comment: Run the query manually (via mysql interface, or through console) and does it error?

Comment: your query is wrong, google mysql left join for the correct syntax. when you fix your query, fatal error will be fixed alone

Answer (score 1):

You have an error on your SQL query.
Try this

```
SELECT posts.Email, posts.Text, members.Img_url
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN members 
    ON members.Email = posts.Email
WHERE posts.ForumId = '$forumId'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `prepare()` query is failing, so `$stmt` is a non-object. It looks like your query syntax is wrong as you can't have a `LEFT JOIN` after `WHERE`, and `JOIN` uses `ON` not `WHERE`. Try something like this-

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT posts.Email,posts.Text, members.Img_url FROM posts LEFT JOIN   members ON members.Email = posts.Email  WHERE posts.ForumId = '$forumId'") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT posts.Email, posts.Text, members.Img_url
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN members ON members.Email = posts.Email
WHERE posts.ForumId = '$forumId'
```

You should really check out the syntaxes of mysql.. You made a few mistakes here ;)
I hope it works like this.